Installation issue in Team's Scope when changing the tab order when using a bot and static tabs in a Teams app?
We have an app MS Teams App Store. We have built a static tab that is available in personal as well as teams’ scope. We also have a bot (team and personal scope) as part of the complete app.
We wanted to show our static tab as the first tab (i.e. before the chat tab).

We referred the following 2 link and made the mention changes in our manifest file.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-personal-tab?pivots=razor-csharp&tabs=vs#reorder-static-personal-tabs
Is it possible to change the tab order when when using a bot and static tabs in a Teams app?
Changes in Manifest file:
{
   "staticTabs":[
      {
         //Our Tab Details
      },
      {
         "entityId":"conversations",
         "scopes":[
            "personal"
         ]
      }
   ]
}

After making the changes in our manifest file, we are seeing the following behavior.

We are not able install the bot in teams. Nothing happens when we try to add the bot in teams' scope. Our bot API end points are not getting called.
If we try to add the bot in personal scope, it gets added properly and I can see the static tab as the first tab. This works correctly but it's causing issue with Team's scope.

Any Idea?

Hello @Devesh - Reorder of tab is applicable to personal scope bot only and you should use manifest version 1.17.
If we add the same bot in Teams scope we are also not able to add the bot in Teams channel scope. I think it's by design behavior.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-personal-tab?pivots=razor-csharp&tabs=vs#reorder-static-personal-tabs     https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema
